# Set property value not working between ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I'm trying to build Facebook login function using the facebook SDK.  Now I have login viewcontroller with facebook login button and profile viewcontroller which will show after click the button. There are a few items need to show in profile viewcontroller like profilephoto,name etc, these information can get from facebook response, so my plan is to pass the "profile" data from login viewcontroller to profile viewcontroller, below is sample code in login viewcontroller.

my problem now is I found the "profile" data was not passed at all which inside  "DispatchQueue.main.async" below, the data passing working when I use segue(override func prepare) in other viewcontrollers, not sure why not working here in the sub thread, can anyone help me to solve this issue, many thanks

```
 if let accessToken=FBSDKAccessToken.current(){
        print("FB permissions:\(accessToken.permissions)")

        let graphRequest=FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id,name,email"])
        let connection=FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
        connection.add(graphRequest, completionHandler:
            {(connection,result,error) in
                let data = result as! [String:AnyObject]
                let name = data["name"] as! String
                let id = data["id"] as! String
                //let email = data["email"] as! String

                print("inside the calling...name:\(name)")

                self.profile?.name=name
                //self.profile?.email=email
                if let url=URL(string:"https://graph.facebook.com/\(id)/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1"),
                    let dataImage = try? Data(contentsOf:url){
                    self.profile?.profilePhoto=UIImage(data:dataImage)
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let homeVC=self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController
                    homeVC.profile=self.profile
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeVC, animated: true)

                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
        } )
        connection.start()
    }
```

Comment: Is the `pushViewController` happening?  How do you check whether the data is being passed?  If you put a breakpoint on `pushViewController` and inspect `homeVC`, do you see the profile data in its property?

Comment: I got it resolved. it is my bad, actually the thing is I never init the data structure "profile", but set the value directly like "self.profile?.name=name" etc. so I debug and found the self.profile still be nil even some member of it was set with some value, stupid mistake:(  And thanks for your help and suggestion